# Select Value In Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to automate the account registration on https://outlook.live.com/owa/

I came as far as here:

[image]

I couldn't use `from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select` to select either `outlook.com` or `hotmail.com` from the dropdown menu.

I tried:

```
Select(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'select')).select_by_value('hotmail.com')
```

My Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\outlook\start.py", line 13, in <module>
    create_email(settings, driver)

  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\outlook\bot\create_email.py", line 14, in create_email
    Select(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'select')).select_by_value('hotmail.com')

  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 87, in select_by_value
    raise NoSuchElementException("Cannot locate option with value: %s" % value)

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Cannot locate option with value: hotmail.com
```

HTML code of the site:

```
<select class="phoneCountry col-xs-24 win-dropdown" id="LiveDomainBoxList" name="LiveDomainBoxList" aria-label="Email domain options" data-bind="options: domains, value: domain, hasFocus: isLiveDomainDropDownFocused, disable: memberName.isValidating(), css: {'win-dropdown': config.isWin10HostOOBEDesktop !== 0}">
    <option value="outlook.com">outlook.com</option>
    <option value="hotmail.com">hotmail.com</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT:**

Instead of `By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'select'`

I used `By.XPATH, '//*[@id="LiveDomainBoxList"]'`

and it's working. But I still want to use `By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'select'`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want use by `css selector` use  the same `id` to identify the element.

```
Select(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#LiveDomainBoxList')).select_by_value('hotmail.com')
```